# Is passing a variable by reference to a function makes the function inline

Tags: c++

**Background**

Reference does not have any memory allocation, it is just another name of the variable.  If we pass a variable by reference, it is not stored on the callee function stack (to avoid breaking the "A reference is just an alias" concept).
So compiler should copy the callee function body into the caller function itself (I named it making function inline for understanding).

However inline functions have its own rules to consider a function inline.

I completely understand that compiler must play an important role here. It should convert references to pointers on compilation depending on the complexity.
I would like to understand the rules generally compiler applies in these cases.

**Case 1:**

```
void func(const int& a)
{
    // hudge processing, at least 500 lines of
    // code including loops
    // Will it becomes inline
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
void func(const Person& p)
{
    // Person is a user defined type
    // Person is large class has stl containers
    // hudge processing, at least 500 lines of
    // code including loops
    // Will it becomes inline?
}
```

**Case 3:**

```
void func(const Machine& d)
{
    // Machine is a user defined type
    // func call func recursively multiple times
    // If it becomes inline then it will increase the binary size
}
```

Comment: Passing by reference and inline are different things. What do you mean ?

Comment: If we pass a variable by reference, there is no memory assigned to the reference variable. So calling function must use the same stack to save the variable. If it is true, then the compiler has to make function inline.

Comment: `variable by reference, there is no memory assigned to the reference variable` but there is. Exactly `sizeof(int&)` memory for a `int` reference.

Comment: Passing a variable by reference generates exactly the same CPU instructions as passing the variable by pointer. A function call will normally be done (if not placed `inline`, at optimizer discretion) with the _address_ of the object as argument.

Comment: If this were true, then a struct with a reference in it would require everything that uses it to be inline. And how would a vector of such structures work?

Comment: complier should convert reference to pointer for complex cases. even @prapin says, CPU instruction are same for both passing reference and pointer

Comment: @Anil8753 Raymond was responding to your question, not the previous comments. He is pointing out that your original assumptions can not be true for the reason he gave. References and pointers are the same to the compiler not only in complex cases but always.

Answer (score 1):

No. A compiler will not inline the function just because arguments are references.

Technically, *references* and *pointers* are strictly the same thing: a *memory address* pointing to some object.
C++ syntax distinguish between references and pointers, but the compiler considers the two concepts as equivalent and will generate the same code whether you pass a variable by reference or by pointer to a function.

In **case 1** you are passing a `const int&` argument to `func`. While this is perfectly allowed, it typically doesn't make sense since it is cheaper to copy a `int` variable (normally 4 bytes), than to pass the address of it (8 bytes on 64-bit platform). The called function will need to dereference the address to obtain the value, and this can also prevent some optimizations. It is recommended to pass by reference only variables that are costly to copy.

Comment: How can you prove this answer? Did you check the assembly code?

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaBellamkonda Yes, a few times in the past. Now I know that compilers are getting more and more clever when optimizing. But I can inverse the question: for a method taking a reference as argument that is not inlined, how else could the compiler support the reference without passing the address of the variable?